# python elementree blank output

Tags: python, xml, linux, elementtree

I am parsing an XML output from VCloud, however I am not able to reach to the values

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SupportedVersions xmlns="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/versions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/versions http://10.10.6.12/api/versions/schema/versions.xsd">
        <VersionInfo>
            <Version>1.5</Version>
            <LoginUrl>https://api.vcd.portal.skyscapecloud.com/api/sessions</LoginUrl>
            <MediaTypeMapping>
                <MediaType>application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.instantiateVAppTemplateParams+xml</MediaType>
                <ComplexTypeName>InstantiateVAppTemplateParamsType</ComplexTypeName>
                <SchemaLocation>http://api.vcd.portal.skyscapecloud.com/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd</SchemaLocation>
            </MediaTypeMapping>
            <MediaTypeMapping>
                <MediaType>application/vnd.vmware.admin.vmwProviderVdcReferences+xml</MediaType>
                <ComplexTypeName>VMWProviderVdcReferencesType</ComplexTypeName>
                <SchemaLocation>http://api.vcd.portal.skyscapecloud.com/api/v1.5/schema/vmwextensions.xsd</SchemaLocation>
            </MediaTypeMapping>
            <MediaTypeMapping>
                <MediaType>application/vnd.vmware.vcloud.customizationSection+xml</MediaType>
                <ComplexTypeName>CustomizationSectionType</ComplexTypeName>
                <SchemaLocation>http://api.vcd.portal.skyscapecloud.com/api/v1.5/schema/master.xsd</SchemaLocation>
            </MediaTypeMapping>
```

this is what I have been using

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = ET.fromstring(content)
versioninfo = data.findall("VersionInfo/Version")
print len(versioninfo)
print versioninfo.text
```

however this gives a blank output...any suggestions?

Comment: I don't believe it prints a blank output. Surely `print len(versioninfo)` prints **something**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = ET.fromstring(content)
versioninfo = data.find(
    "ns:VersionInfo/ns:Version",
    namespaces={'ns':'http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/versions'})
print versioninfo.text
```

- Use `.find()`, not `.findall()` to return a single element
- Your XML uses namespaces. The full path to your desired object is: `'{http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/versions}VersionInfo/{http://www.vmware.com/vcloud/versions}Version'` By passing in the `namespaces` parameter, you are able to use the shortcut syntax: `ns:VersionInfo/ns:Version`.